# Add thousand separator to gnome calculator in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-calculator

Gnome-Calculator used to have a menu option to add a thousand separators when typing large numbers

1000000 -> 1,000,000

10000 -> 10,000

Is there a way to do it in Gnome-Calculator v3.28.1 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: have you checked this [How to show comma seperation in numbers on ubuntu's calculator?](https://askubuntu.com/q/737376/283843)

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [Big Number Calculator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098530/calculator-in-human-readable-format/1099280#1099280)

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding this too. Have a look at the Calculator dropdown item next to Activities. You'll find the Preferences menu there.

[image: gnome-calculator-preferences]