# Big Number Calculator (human readable format)

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a calculator suitable for large numbers where a letter can be entered instead of a whole bunch of zeros:

- `K (Kilo) 000`
- `M (Mega) 000,000` .............................. Million
- `G (Giga) 000,000,000` ....................... Billion
- `T (Tera) 000,000,000,000` ............... Trillion
- `P (Peta) 000,000,000,000,000` ........ Quadtrillion
- `E (Exa)  000,000,000,000,000,000` . Quintrillion

For example $20 trillion dollars / 50 million units would be entered as:

```
20t / 50m
```

The result is 400,000 and can be displayed as `400 K`.

Is there already a calculator for Ubuntu / Debian for Big Numbers (aka Human Readable format)?

My question is similar to these questions but not a duplicate:

- [Add thousand separator to gnome calculator in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068071/add-thousand-separator-to-gnome-calculator-in-ubuntu-18-04/1099419?noredirect=1#comment1813867_1099419)
- [How to show comma separation in numbers on Ubuntu's calculator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737376/how-to-show-comma-seperation-in-numbers-on-ubuntus-calculator/1099421#1099421)

The letters used such as T for Tera (Trillion) or G for Giga (Billion), etc. come from industry standards. Standards are set by  [Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_of_Electrical_and_Electronics_Engineers) (IEEE).

---

**Edit:** A few days after original question was posted, this turned into a self-answered question. Original answers though and alternative suggestions are welcome and would likely interest others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Big Number Calculator*** is an indispensable calculator
for math equations using **MB** (Megabytes), **GB** (Gigabytes),
**TB** (Terabytes), etc.

**EDIT:** Originally posted in 2018. Updated in September 2023. Screenshot is out-of-date because bottom row of keys are now ordered as <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>.

There is a new [Big Number Calculaor Video](https://www.pippim.com/programs/mserve.html#sample-big-number-calculator-video)  showing the revised key layout. The new video has additional instructions.

## Sample Calculator Window

[image: Big Number Calculator - calc.py.gif]

- Type `100K` for 100,000 users
- Type `x` to multiply
- Type `100` for $100 per month
- Type `=`
- The result will be displayed as `10 M` ($10 million dollars).

So 10 million dollars a month is what you can expect for 100,000 users paying $100 / month.

## Python Script - calc.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Author: pippim.com
License: GNU GPLv3. (c) 2018 - 2023
Source: This repository
Description: mserve - Music Server - Calculator for big numbers
"""

from __future__ import print_function  # Must be first import
from __future__ import with_statement  # Error handling for file opens
from __future__ import division  # eval() returns .3333 for (1/3)
import warnings  # 'warnings' advises which commands aren't supported
warnings.simplefilter('default')  # in future Python versions.

# NAME: calc.py
# DATE: December 8, 2018 - Ported to mserve September 7, 2023
# DESC: Calculator in E-Exa, P-Peta, T-Tera, G-Giga, M-Mega and K-Kilo
# NOTE: Requires Tkinter GUI libraries: sudo apt install python-tk
# UPDT: Sep. 07 2023 - Conform to PEP rules. Support Python 2 and 3 simultaneously.
#           Divide by zero error message. Decimal point entered error message.
#           Support 2 floating point decimal division results converted to UoM. 
#           Support square and square root UoM not in 2018 version.

# Majority Credit to: 
# https://www.techinfected.net/2016/02/make-gui-calculator-in-python-windows-linux.html

try:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.font as font
    PYTHON_VER = "3"
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont as font
    PYTHON_VER = "2"

import math


class Calculator:
    """ Big Number Calculator"""
    def get_and_replace(self):
        """ Replace 'x' with '*' and '÷' with '/' 
            Expand K to 1000, M to 1000000, etc. 
            Whole numbers only, else 1.2k becomes 1.2000 s/b 1200
        """
        self.expression = self.e.get()
        self.new_text = self.expression.replace('÷'.decode('utf-8'), '/')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('x', '*')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace(' ', '')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.upper()
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('K', '000')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('M', '000000')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('G', '000000000')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('T', '000000000000')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('P', '000000000000000')
        self.new_text = self.new_text.replace('E', '000000000000000000')

    def equals(self):
        """ When the equal button is pressed, calculate result """
        self.get_and_replace()
        if "." in self.new_text:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.e.insert(0, 'Decimals invalid')
            return
        try:
            # evaluate the expression using the eval function
            self.value = eval(self.new_text) 
        except SyntaxError or NameErrror:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.e.insert(0, 'Invalid Input!')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.e.insert(0, 'Divide By Zero!')
        else:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            # Give result in K, M, G, T, P or E
            self.e.insert(0, self.convert())

    def convert(self):
        """ convert to UoM with lowest whole number method """
        #2**10 = 1024  # Used to be MiB now MB, future switch to toggle between
        power = 1000.0
        size = float(self.value)
        n = 0
        Dic_powerN = {0: '', 1: 'K', 2: 'M', 3: 'G', 4: 'T', 5: 'P', 6: 'E'}
        while size > power:
            size /= power
            n += 1
        uom = " ?" if n > 6 else " " + Dic_powerN[n]
        return '{:2f}'.format(size).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + uom

    def square_root(self):
        """ square root method """
        self.get_and_replace()
        try:
            # evaluate the expression using the eval function
            self.value = eval(self.new_text)
        except SyntaxError or NameErrror:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.e.insert(0, 'Invalid Input!')
        else:
            #self.sqrt_val = math.sqrt(self.value)
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.value = math.sqrt(self.value)
            self.e.insert(0, self.convert())

    def square(self):
        """ square method """
        self.get_and_replace()
        try:
            # evaluate the expression using the eval function
            self.value = eval(self.new_text)
        except SyntaxError or NameErrror:
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.e.insert(0, 'Invalid Input!')
        else:
            #self.sqr_val = math.pow(self.value, 2)
            self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
            #self.e.insert(0, self.sqr_val)
            self.value = math.pow(self.value, 2)
            self.e.insert(0, self.convert())

    def clear_all(self):
        """ When clear button is pressed, clear the text input area """
        self.e.delete(0, tk.END)

    def clear1(self):
        """  Clear display and memory """
        self.txt = self.e.get()[:-1]
        self.e.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.e.insert(0, self.txt)

    def action(self, argi):
        """ Pressed button's value is inserted into the end of the text area """
        self.e.insert(tk.END, argi)

    def __init__(self, master, disp_font, geom=None):
        """ Global variables """
        self.value = None
        self.txt = None
        self.expression = None
        self.new_text = None

        """ Constructor method """
        master.title('Big Number Calculator')
        # Geometry in format "+X+Y" or "WIDxHGT+X+Y" ('x' and '+' required)
        master.geometry(geom)  # Geom None when called from mainloop

        self.e = tk.Entry(master, font=disp_font)
        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, pady=3)
        self.e.focus_set()  # Sets focus on the input text area

        # Generating Buttons
        tk.Button(master, text="=", width=8, command=lambda: self.equals()).\
            grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2)
        tk.Button(master, text='AC', width=3, command=lambda: self.clear_all()).\
            grid(row=1, column=4)
        tk.Button(master, text='C', width=3, command=lambda: self.clear1()).\
            grid(row=1, column=5)
        tk.Button(master, text="+", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('+')).\
            grid(row=4, column=3)
        tk.Button(master, text="x", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('x')).\
            grid(row=2, column=3)
        tk.Button(master, text="-", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('-')).\
            grid(row=3, column=3)
        tk.Button(master, text="÷", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('÷')).\
            grid(row=1, column=3)
        tk.Button(master, text="%", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('%')).\
            grid(row=4, column=2)
        tk.Button(master, text="7", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('7')).\
            grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(master, text="8", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(8)).\
            grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text="9", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(9)).\
            grid(row=1, column=2)
        tk.Button(master, text="4", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(4)).\
            grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Button(master, text="5", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(5)).\
            grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text="6", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(6)).\
            grid(row=2, column=2)
        tk.Button(master, text="1", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(1)).\
            grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Button(master, text="2", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(2)).\
            grid(row=3, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text="3", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(3)).\
            grid(row=3, column=2)
        tk.Button(master, text="0", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(0)).\
            grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Button(master, text=".", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('.')).\
            grid(row=4, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text="(", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('(')).\
            grid(row=2, column=4)
        tk.Button(master, text=")", width=3, command=lambda: self.action(')')).\
            grid(row=2, column=5)
        tk.Button(master, text="√", width=3, command=lambda: self.square_root()).\
            grid(row=3, column=4)
        tk.Button(master, text="x²", width=3, command=lambda: self.square()).\
            grid(row=3, column=5)
        tk.Button(master, text="K", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('K')).\
            grid(row=5, column=0)
        tk.Button(master, text="M", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('M')).\
            grid(row=5, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text="G", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('G')).\
            grid(row=5, column=2)
        tk.Button(master, text="T", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('T')).\
            grid(row=5, column=3)
        tk.Button(master, text="P", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('P')).\
            grid(row=5, column=4)
        tk.Button(master, text="E", width=3, command=lambda: self.action('E')).\
            grid(row=5, column=5)


def main():
    """ Make root mainloop and objectify Calculator class """
    root = tk.Tk()
    # Larger font for HDPI screen
    default_font = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    default_font.configure(size=11)
    display_font = "Calibri 13"
    obj = Calculator(root, display_font)  # object instantiated
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# End of calc.py
```

You can get the [calc.py python script](https://github.com/pippim/mserve/blob/main/src/calc.py)  source code from GitHub.

## Install Tkinter

You need `python-tk` (**Tkinter**) installed to use Python GUI Calculator. It is already installed in most Linux distributions and all of Windows and MAC. If missing in your Linux distribution use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-tk
```

Comment: Tk is part of standard python library, so you should not need to install it unless your OS uses python minimal package.  +1, looks very nice

Answer (score 4):

> For example $20 trillion dollars / 50 million taxpayers would be entered as:
>
> 20t / 50m

I will do a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843)

The answer here isn't to find software that supports this format, but to learn a *standard* format used in both calculators, programming languages and math: [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

You write a number as a base (significand) and an exponent, e.g. 2*10⁵ for 20000. 20 trillions is thus 2*10¹³ - or 20*10¹². This will work on nearly all calculators, allows for compact and *exact* numbers, *independently* of language. Billion may for instance mean both 10⁹ and 10¹², depending on culture.

In addition, this allows you to [clearly define significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), as you may write 7.0*10³ or 7.02*10³, to note the number of known decimals.

In computers this may additionally be written as *n*e*y* for *n**10^*y*, for instance 5e6 is interpreted as 5*10⁶. This form can be used in for instance `octave`.

Comment: But this doesn't help the OP deal with MB vs MiB etc, as requested in the question. And don't try to tell me those can be expressed using 10 or 2 as a base respectively :). That's perfectly true but also perfectly irrelevant to this question. An answer suggesting someone learn a different notation instead of giving a solution with the notation requested isn't answering the question.

Comment: @terdon That’s because one of the questions’ premises is wrong: That something like “20t” is unambiguous. It could mean “20 thousand”, “20 trillion”, “20 tons” (= 20 million), … Sometimes a question is best answered not as OP intended. Yes, I call this an XY problem.

Comment: Sure, and "20t" could also mean "20 things" or "20 taps" but the OP defined it as "20 trillion". If that's your problem, ask the OP to clarify, but this is still answering a different question (which, had it been asked here would have been off topic anyway: we don't answer basic math questions here).

Comment: @terdon It's an answer to OP's question, as it provides an explanation for why you do not need this. If a user asks how to do something, and there is better and more universal solutions, the user should be made *aware* of that.

Comment: @dessert "20K" is used for 20 thousand in the question. I've updated the answer with a `.gif` today.