# Basic GUI calcutor for Ubuntu

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator, gcalctool

I am asking a question here that seems to be ridiculous.  I'm just letting everyone know I am aware of this is advance.  (How does Ubuntu not come with a functional calculator???)

For Ubuntu 16.04.

I am looking for a basic calculator that has "M+" "MC" "MR" "+/-" and a Clear button (the first three are memory).  I prefer that it doesn't have you type in your formula, but rather does a "*" when you press the button, but I will accept that if there aren't other options.  I'm not interested in calculators that require documentation to use (you have to know what "Ctrl-X does, which you can't learn from the calculators menus).

You can skip the rest of this if you don't want more details.

Thanks

I have tried gcalc, calculator, gnome-calculate, and Qalculate!.  The last one lets you save a variable, which you have to name (cumbersome), but I have no idea how to find the variable later - "history" doesn't show stored variable names, and there are no other buttons to try.  The variable "A" comes predefined??? I'm not going to read the documentation for it, as I hate the interface, it's formula based, doesn't have a clear button, and for other reasons.  I have no idea why the developers of the first three calculators think their products are functional without having a memory.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe speedcrunch? I don't know for certain but it may be your best shot

Comment: I don't think there's any need for "How does Ubuntu not come with a functional calculator" with three question marks. Just because it doesn't simulate a pocket calculator, doesn't mean calculator isn't a functional calculator. Real pocket calculators have memory buttons because they're not personal computers. Have you considered using ctrl+c and ctrl+v (aka copy and paste) to do the same job???

Comment: @Au101 That would work in some cases, but not when you need a cumulative total, with several intermediate calculations.  M+ adds whatever the current result is to what's currently in memory.

Comment: Have a look at:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098530/big-number-calculator-human-readable-format?noredirect=1&lq=1 and use the unmodified version. I set up the answer and can modify the python script for you.

Comment: @dsSTORM  I downloaded that, and it doesn't match the screen on their website - no menus.  I got version 0.10.1, and they are at version .12.  I tried to upgrade it (it should have installed the latest), but it said I already have the latest.  Ctrl-M doesn't give a menu.  (There's a complaint about the current version - where they took way the ability to hide the menu with Ctrl-M.)  I updated my question to specify "for Ubuntu 16.0.4."   Apparently the later versions aren't supported on my OS version.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - You are going to write code to add memory buttons to that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this will fit better in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was thinking Memory plus with another button to enter memo/description. Then later letter `P` to print. Not sure if people would find that useful though? I've been meaning to enhance anyway as some requested order of Trillion, Billion and Million be flipped around.

Answer (score 0):

xcalc is perfect, and it's already on the system (x11-apps).  It's just like a pocket calculator, has memory, and additionally has factorial and parenthesis.